# What are the standard formats of publications for journals and conferences?

Tags: publications, mathematics, paper-submission

I am interested in journals of finance and the conference in mathematical and computational finance. Few give the template in the website, while few others don't.Where can i find some standard template?

Comment: Are you sure these journals require you to format your manuscript?

Answer (score 3):

Most will have the template under Author Guidelines or similar. Almost all will have a Microsoft Word template, and many journals in the computational area will also have a LaTeX template available too.

The other place to look is the author guidelines. They may have provided a list of formatting requirements, which might be quite specific or may be vague enough.

If they really don't have one, I would suggest leaving it in the standard Word document template. Some publishers take the input document and then put it into their own layout system, and the fewer the formatting changes the better.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Peadar's answer, I also suggest checking the "early view" section of many journals for accepted preprints. These will often be helpful for you to format your manuscripts.

Comment: Just grab a copy of the journal (or recent papers that are offered on the 'web). They should give you some ideas. If it is a journal from a large publisher (i.e., Springer, Elsevier) they probably have some form of "general" formatting guidelines.